# Tests success on Eclipse and fail on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testing

When I run my tests in eclipse they work with no problems, however, when I try to run them on jenkins most of them get timeout errors or fail to find css selectors. Does anyone know a solution to why my selenium tests work on eclipse but generate issues in jenkins?

example of 1 issue

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: #q_386115 (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```